# Ext associations

Tags: extjs, extjs4, associations

I have a question: The “associations” feature (HasMany-belongsTo) of ExtJs library is applicable only in nested JSON data? Is it doable to define two different stores with two different data retrieving “urls” (and two different models with the association definition?) and the “hasMany” works? Or, I have to define only one store (with one data retrieving “url” and a JSON output that is nested and reflects the data associations of the database) and then with the help of models “format” the data in a way that Ext can consume?
If the second case it is true, how someone could handle large volume data (let’s say a blog: users=>blog-post=>blog-reply) using the Ext “association” feature?
Sorry for my abstract writing style,
Tom,
Greece

Comment: I would recommend not to handle large volume of data on the client side - it has no purpose. End use can only take in a page worth of info at a time and the rest should be paged/sorted/searched/filtered on the server.

Comment: Can you explain to me how hasmany relation works? Is it a requirement to load a json that will hold all the data (with relations)?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Take a look at the sencha guides om how they recommend you use it. I don't think its ready fro prime time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use associations in Ext with large amount of data in any kind of formats as long as you define the corespondent Reader. Using very large datasets will also need a pagination mechanism along with a lazy loading mechanism. You will rarely need to load an entire tree at a time.

Ext provides you with these means. Read more  inside their documentations regarding: Store, Proxy, Reader. Or ask here.